# How to collect list values in to collector object

Tags: collectors

I am trying to collect 2 data fields from the list object.

I am using Employee object:

```
public class Employee
{

  private long id;
  private Source source;
  private String name;
  private String gender;

  // getters
   private Builder toBuilder(Builder builder)
    {
        builder.id = this.summaryDataId;
        builder.name = this.name;
        builder.gender = this.gender;
        builder.source = this.source;
        return builder;
    }
```

getting employee data into a list in a service class

```
final List<Employee> employeeData = employeeDao.retrieveEmployeeData(emp.getID());
```

and then trying to create a list with employeeId and sourceid (Ex: 1234:3). for this I am trying to use collectors.toList

```
List<String> employeeCollector = employeeData.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getId != null)
                .filter(s -> s.getSource() != null && s.getSource().getId() != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

how do i get employeeid:souceid format using collectors.toLis()

Answer (score 1):

You just need an intermediate operation `map` to extract the employee id and source id

```
List<String> employeeCollector = employeeData.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getId != null)
            .filter(s -> s.getSource() != null && s.getSource().getId() != null)
            .map(s-> String.format("%s:%s",s.getId(),s.getSource().getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```